# Powershell: ConvertFrom-Json doesn't get the variable assigned due to forward and backward compatibility

Tags: powershell, hyper-v, slash

I am trying to load a variables into powershell from variables.json having the following

```
{
    "psfp":  "C:/San\/SV65\/ps",
    "vmfp": "'C:/San\/SV65\/hyper-packer\/hyper-packer\/output-centos8-9\/Virtual Machines'",
    "psmp": "C:/San\/SV65\/ps",
    "vmname": ""
}
```

Trying to import with

```
$jvariables=Get-Content -Raw -Path '.\variables-ps.json' | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Output on powershell

```
PS C:\San\SV65\ps> Write-host $jvariables.psfp
C:/San/SV65/ps

PS C:\San\SV65\ps> Write-host $jvariables.vmfp
'C:/San/SV65/hyper-packer/hyper-packer/output-centos8-9/Virtual Machines'

PS C:\San\SV65\ps> Write-host $jvariables.psmp
C:/San/SV65/ps
```

These forward slash not incompatible on powershell for a windows path! ConvertFrom-Json doesn't accept backslash on the variables tried with '' as well

Hence could not load my modules on these path

any other way to achieve the above case?
Want to use json as it easy for the end user to update rather a txt files

Please share

Answer (score 2):

you can loop through the object properties and change the path separator like this:

```
$jvariables.psobject.properties | where {$_.membertype -eq "NoteProperty"} | 
foreach {$data.($_.name) = $_.value.replace("/","\")}
```

or a simpler approach would be to escape backslash in config file, like this :

```
{
"psfp":  "C:\\San\\SV65\\ps",
"vmfp": "'C:\\San\\SV65\\hyper-packer\\hyper-packer\\output-centos8-9\\Virtual Machines'",
"psmp": "C:\\San\\SV65\\ps",
"vmname": ""

}
```